# Flexible mirror for anamorphic art illusion

Tags: mirror

I am looking for a flexible mirror that can be folded into a cylinder so as to use in the [cylindrical anamorphic illusions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7o9_y2eLPQ). In the same video, the guy has shown the silver sheet, I would like to know the name of the same.

Any idea what it is called and from where we can buy it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I have some of this from when I did contemporary photography years ago. Unfortunately, I don't remember where I got it (might have been given to me). Search for *mirror mylar roll*. A lot of it is 2 mil thick, this is a little thin, it will not hold a shape well. Try to get 4 mil (0.1 mm) if you can.